# I get following exception intermitently when i drag and drop the custom control(derived from TableLayoutPanel) into Winform Designer. Any insight?

Tags: c#

> UTC Timestamp: 11/22/2017 7:35:18 AM Local Timestamp: 11/22/2017
>   3:35:18 PM Message: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside
>   the bounds of the array.   at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Design.Behavior.TableLayoutPanelBehavior.IndexOfNextStealableStyle(Boolean
>   forward, Int32 startIndex, Int32[] widths)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Design.Behavior.TableLayoutPanelBehavior.CanResizeStyle(Int32[]
>   widths)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Design.Behavior.TableLayoutPanelBehavior.OnMouseDown(Glyph
>   g, MouseButtons button, Point mouseLoc)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Design.Behavior.BehaviorService.OnMouseDown(MouseButtons
>   button, Point mouseLoc)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Design.Behavior.BehaviorService.AdornerWindow.WndProcProxy(Message&
>   m, Int32 x, Int32 y)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Design.Behavior.BehaviorService.AdornerWindow.MouseHook.ProcessMouseMessage(IntPtr
>   hWnd, Int32 msg, Int32 x, Int32 y)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Design.Behavior.BehaviorService.AdornerWindow.MouseHook.MouseHookProc(Int32
>   nCode, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.GetMessageW(MSG& msg,
>   HandleRef hWnd, Int32 uMsgFilterMin, Int32 uMsgFilterMax)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr
>   dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.RunDialog(Form form)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)    at
>   ConfigForm.LaunchForm(String xmlContent)

Comment: Not without your code no.

Comment: You have to test to make sure item is > left, > top, <left + width, < top + height.